# How to Properly Add an Image to the Activity

Tags: android, xml, image, android-activity

In the activity, I add an image through adding an ImageView and then adding my desired picture from the hdpi folder(its the only folder I'm allowed to select pictures from). However, there is one problem. I notice that when I add the picture and run it, there is an error. Basically I noticed that if the image is 72 pixels by 72 pixels, the app will run. However, when I compress it to 72 pixels by 72 pixels and run the app, the picture ends up being way too small.Is there any way I can just add the original picture to the Activity without compressing it all the way to 72 pixels by 72 pixels. By the way, I tried "enlarging" the 72 by 72 compressed picture by dragging on its corners, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please post your xml and code where you are adding the image

Comment: @Rohit5k2
How do I add my code here? It's too many characters for a normal comment.

Comment: @Cyb edit ur question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use match parent or fill parent xml property to do that but image will get distorted if we programmatically make it bigger, we can pass the size too in image view height and width here is what you can try.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image200" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or you can pass size in dp i.e, 200dp in width and 300dp in height, but i suggest that you should use image of proper size other wise it distort.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your own 'nodpi' folder, and putting image there. This is what my searching led me to do.